# Accessing Objects inside lists

Tags: c#, list, class, object

I am making a 'Quiz type' program, where the questions are read from a file, stored as objects and then stored in a list.
I have no idea how to check if they have been stored correctly, so I'll post the storage code too.

My problem is that I seem not to be able to access any of the data I have stored.
For example:

```
vartrack.Questions[0].MultipleChoice;
```

This should return true or false?
But for some reason I cannot access the MultipleChoice data.

My code is as follows:
Class code:

```
public class QuizQuestions
{
    public bool MultipleChoice = false;
    public string questiontext;
    public static List<string> Answers = new List<string>();
    public bool correct;
    public QuizQuestions(string QuestionText)
    {
        questiontext = QuestionText;
    }
    public void AddAnswer(string answer)
    {
        Answers.Add(answer);
        if (Answers.Count > 1)
        {
            MultipleChoice = true;
        }
    }
}
```

The rest of the code:

```
foreach(string currentline in vartrack.QuestionLines)
            {
                if (Question)
                {
                    current = new QuizQuestions(currentline);
                    vartrack.Questions.Add(current);
                    Question = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (currentline == "#")
                    {
                        Question = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (current != null)
                        {
                           current.AddAnswer(currentline);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            int num;
            while (vartrack.Questions.Count > inputNoOfQs.Value)
            {
                Random random = new Random();
                num = random.Next(0, vartrack.Questions.Count);
                vartrack.Questions.RemoveAt(num);
            }
            vartrack.Questions[0].MultipleChoice;
```

Thanks

EDIT 1:
Vartrack is defined here:

```
    public static class vartrack
{
    public static string[] QuestionSets;
    public static List<string> QuestionLines = new List<string>();
    public static List<object> Questions = new List<object>();

}
```

Comment: You aren't storing any of your variables. You're just calling methods randomly.. So, you can't access them because you're not trying to.

Comment: I have removed my answer as it was not the problem. What exactly is the error you are getting? What do you expect and what happens?

Comment: The error is:
Error 2 'object' does not contain a definition for 'MultipleChoice' and no extension method 'MultipleChoice' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

And I would expect to be able to access the information in the object!
EDIT: I know the code there doesn't do anything, it was in an if statement, but I removed it for ease of reading.

Comment: Think you may need to provide more code listing where is vartrack defined?

Comment: Show us how you've defined `vartrack`.

Comment: Something a little offtopic: why dont you use XML? There are already implemented(and included) ways of moving objects(serializing) to files and back, plus at cost of some extra space it can be easily read and edited out of your program.

Comment: I'm not the worlds most competent coder, and I always find experience useful.
Secondly, (and perhaps more importantly?) it's a piece of coursework, and the work has to be my own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
public static List<object> Questions = new List<object>();
```

You want this:

```
public static List<QuizQuestions> Questions = new List<QuizQuestions>();
```

When you retrieve items from your list.. they are `object`. `object` doesn't have a `MultipleChoice` property.. but `QuizQuestions` does. So that's what you want to define your list as.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is here, each time you are changing current instance,and adding it to your list.So your list might have 20 questions, but they will be same question if you doing like this:

```
current = new QuizQuestions(currentline);
vartrack.Questions.Add(current);
```

Instead you should create a completely new instance like this:

```
var question = new QuizQuestions(currentline);
vartrack.Questions.Add(question);
current = question;
```

I suggest you to make your `MultipleChoice` a property like this:

```
public bool MultipleChoice { get; set; }
```

And your list definition is wrong.

Change this:

```
public static List<object> Questions = new List<object>();
```

To this:

```
public static List<QuizQuestions> Questions = new List<QuizQuestions>();
```

If you define a `List<object>` , you can't access your `MultipleChoice` property because `Object` class doesn't have a `MultipleChoice` property.

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks!
Just out of curiosity, what is the point of the { get; set; } piece of code?
As when I was looking around, I saw it, but I couldn't find anywhere explaining what it did!
Thanks!

Comment: @darkdan21 they are called auto implemented properties. take a look at here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx